# capturing Created Date on custom field

Tags: workflow

I have a requirement where , I have to populate my custom field with the date a record gets created , i used a workflow rule to evaluate on "record creation" and rule criteria as formula set to "true" and update action on my custom field to include "created date", but the custom field never gets the created,any help here pls?

Comment: "populate my custom field with the date a record gets created" why though? Why not use the created date field in SFDC?

Comment: You could at least do your best to share a complete picture of the configuration of your `Workflow Rule`.

Comment: Why not just a create a formula field of DateTime type and have it as `=CreatedDate`? The other benefit of using it that it will let you to show Created Date and Time in report or on the page, when Standard CreatedDate is shown as a Date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just create a field with type:`datetime`

Set default value as `NOW()` and done!

[image]

Comment: Since `CreatedDate` is a `Datetime` field, better to use `NOW()`, no?

Comment: absolutely...updated the answer :)

Comment: I would like to know , why workflow rules which had "createddate" to populated in my custom field did not work ? because , database commit happens after workflow fires ?